# how to delete a row if datatable has any special characters in column?

Tags: c#, datatable

In my Datatable columns have some special characters.so want to delete the rows which have special characters.

MY Data Table:

Name               Contacts

Alex                9848598485

Paul                @9955221100

mic                  #9988552211

i want to delete the second and third row why because it has special characters .
and i take special chars like

```
string [] chars=new string[] { ",", ".", "/", "!", "@", "#", "$", 
 "%", "^", "&", "*", "'", "\"", ";","_", "(", ")", ":", "|", "[", "]" }; 


public void deletespecialchars(DataTable dt, string[] ch)
  {


        ArrayList al = new ArrayList();
      foreach (DataColumn row in dt.Columns)
        {
            if(al.Contains(ch))
                al.Add(row);
            if (al.Count > 0)
            {
                foreach (DataColumn dcol1 in al)
                {
                    dt.Columns.Remove(dcol1);
                }
            }

        }
    }
```

when i call this method like

```
deletespecialchars(dt,chars);
```

i dont remove the special chars.
pls help me

Comment: why you have this characters in first placE ?

Comment: `if(al.Contains(ch))` is never going to be true and thus `if (al.Count > 0)` also will not evaluate to true. Despite that, I don't understand your question.

Comment: Why your columns contain this characters ?

Comment: Sriram Sakthivel,pls give me hint to done this...

Comment: Your code is attempting to remove columns with names containing special chars. Is this what you want? Or do you want to remove special chars from the actual data (table cells)?

Comment: As I said already, I don't understand the question. Please explain it more clearly. but am sure your code will not reach `dt.Columns.Remove(dcol1);`

Comment: mybirthname,i export excel file into datatable and delete if any specila chars...

Comment: "i export excel file into datatable and delete if"...Delete what?

Comment: Sriram Sakthivel:datatable columns have any special characters like @9848598485 or #9848598485 .i want to delete perticular column

Comment: Emmad Kareem:yes i want to delete columns with special chars

Comment: Use the dt.DataColumnName to test instead of the ArrayList. I suspect that you can use special chars in column names any way (maybe except '_'). You should be aware that you are deleting the column and its data contents.

Comment: if any column have any special character delete the Entire row..this is my intension

Comment: I suggest you edit your question and give a clear example of input and expected output.

Comment: @Raamraj Emmad is right and don't forget to say that you're exporting an excel file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example of what you can do based on my understanding ... your variable names and process to load the data will be different. You maybe able to acheave the same result with less code using Regex and Linq.

```
        //array of bad chars you don't want in your data - Must be of char type 
        char [] chars=new char[] { '$','-','#'}; //Add all bad chars here...
        //define and load the datatable
        DataTable dt = new DataTable("test");
        DataColumn c0 = new DataColumn("Contacts");
        dt.Columns.Add(c0);
        DataColumn c1 = new DataColumn("Serial");
        dt.Columns.Add("c1");
        DataColumn c3 = new DataColumn("Notes");
        dt.Columns.Add(c3);
        //load some data
        dt.Rows.Add(new object[]  {"a","1234$542341","no$$tes1"} );
        dt.Rows.Add(new object[]  {"b#","12342241","notes2"} );
        dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "c?", "-421341", "notes3" });
        dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "DD", "12345", "notes3" });

        //loop through each cell, when a cell contains bad data,
        //remove the entire row and skip remainig cells 

        if (dt == null) return;
        Console.WriteLine("Rows before:" + dt.Rows.Count.ToString());
        if (dt.Rows.Count == 0) return;

        int c = dt.Rows.Count;

        for (int r = c-1; r > -1; r--)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("***Row: "); 

            foreach (var item in dt.Rows[r].ItemArray) // Loop over the items.
            {
                if (item.ToString().IndexOfAny(chars) > -1)
                {
                    Console.Write("Bad Content: ");
                    Console.WriteLine(item);
                    dt.Rows[r].Delete(); //remove row
                    break;//skip remaining cells
                }
            }
        }
        dt.AcceptChanges();
        Console.WriteLine("Rows after:"+dt.Rows.Count.ToString());
        Console.Read();
```

Comment: Emmad Kareem,Bhayya,Thankyou Very Much for u r reply...its working.acctually  iam not good in english,so i didnt explain clearly.but you give your response very patiently...thankyou very much..Advance Happy New Year...

Comment: @Raamraj, I appreciate your nice reply, same to you.